# does std::vector::insert allocate spare capacity?

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management

Code like

```
std::vector<int> a;
for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    a.push_back(0);
```

is guaranteed to run in linear time in `n`. This is achieved by allocating some additional spare capacity when reallocating (typically increasing the total capacity by a constant factor).

But what about `std::vector::insert(pos, x)`? I.e. is it guaranteed that

```
std::vector<int> a;
for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    a.insert(a.end(), 0);
```

is linear as well? (similar question applies to `insert(pos, first, last)` of course)

The [documentaiton of `push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) is clear in guaranteeing "amortized constant" complexity.

But the [documentation of `insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) says the complexity should be "constant plus linear in the distance between pos and end of the container". This can obviously only be true if no reallocation happens, thus my uncertainty.

**EDIT:** Summary of the answers: When a reallocation occurs, the implementation can either

1. increase the capacity the bare minimum
2. or increase the capacity more than the minimum, thus making future insertions faster.

In the case of `push_back`, option (2) is essentially required to achieve the "amortized constant" runtime. In the case of `insert(pos, first, last)`, option (2) is required in case of single-pass InputIterator (But in case of multi-pass ForwardIterator, the implementation can and does use a single reallocation with `new_capacity = max(2*old_capacity, new_size)`). All other cases are implementation defined.

Testing with GCC 11 and clang 12, the situation seems to be:

1. `reserve` and `assign` increase capacity by the bare minimum, and
2. `push_back` and `insert` and `resize` increase the capacity by a constant factor

Comment: `a.insert(a.back(), 0);` isn't valid in the first place. [`std::vector::back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back) doesn't refer to an iterator; it is a reference to last-element (and thus why care should be applied to ensure it isn't used on an empty sequence). Pretty sure you meant `end()`.

Comment: it doesnt say "linear in the distance between pos and end of the container" it says "Constant plus linear in the distance between pos and end of the container."

Comment: AFAICT, `insert` is not required to be amortized constant per [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/containers#sequence.reqmts-58) and [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/vector.modifiers#1)

Comment: It's strange that `cppreference` doesn't include the "full complexity". From [Working Draft, Standard for Programming
Language C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf), section 22.3.11.5: "If reallocation happens, linear in the number of elements of the resulting vector; otherwise,
linear in the number of elements inserted plus the distance to the end of the vector". I'd like to find an explanation why this common situation isn't accounted for.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number what constant are they talking about? Either way, it's not constant plus linear, it's linear in the number of elements if reallocation occurs, or linear in the distance between position and end if it doesn't occur.

Comment: @JohnFileau I was wondering the same, I suppose it says "constant plus linear in distance ebtween pos and end" to emphasize that if `pos==end` then it is constant not `O(0)`. And perhaps the constant is refering to reallocations

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I think we can agree that's not constant though. If there's some reference language bible that overloads constant in that way, I'll relent, but this seems like it's worth an edit. I asked on the cppreference channel in the cpplang slack for insight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual language is

> [[vector.overview](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/vector.overview)] A vector is a sequence container that supports (amortized) constant time insert and erase operations at the end; insert and erase in the middle take linear time

and more specifically

> [[vector.modifiers 1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/vector.modifiers#1)] Complexity: If reallocation happens, linear in the number of elements of the resulting vector; otherwise, linear in the number of elements inserted plus the distance to the end of the vector.

but we both agree insert is broadly linear.

When reallocation happens, the options are:

1. reuse the same internal mechanism for growing the vector as in `push_back()`:

   this is obviously still amortized constant time, so the linear-time element move still dominates
2. grow the vector by just one element:

   since this is still linear time, it's still within the complexity allowed. However, it is actually more effort for the implementer, and objectively worse

I don't think I've ever seen an implementation that *didn't* just reuse some internal `grow()` method for both of these, but it would be technically legal to spend more effort doing something worse.

The exception to this reasoning is the range overload `insert(iterator pos, InputIterator begin, InputIterator end)` since, for a strict *LegacyInputIterator*, you can only do one pass.

If you can't pre-calculate the number of elements to grow by, any growth must be amortized constant time, or the overall complexity would be governed by *N * distance(begin,end)*, which could be `O(N²)` and thus non-conformant.

---

tl;dr

- `push_back` must allocate extra capacity to remain amortized constant time
- `insert(pos, begin, end)` must use amortized constant-time growth for each element of `(begin,end]` to remain amortized *linear* time overall
- `insert(pos, value)` does *not* need to allocate extra capacity in order to meet its complexity requirement, but it's probably more effort for the implementer to get a worse result

Comment: Ah yes, didn't think about `insert(pos,first,last)` only being allowed one pass. That solves it in practice I think. Though it could be noted that `a.reserve(a.capacity()+1)` and `a.assign(a.capacity()+1,42)` indeed only grows by one element, whereas `resize`, `insert`, `push_back` seem to share the same internal (exponential) growing mechanism (tested on gcc 11).

Answer (score 1):

"Amortized constant" means "constant most of the time". `push_back` will be O(1) for most of the calls. If reallocation is required, it will be linear, but this should happen relatively rarely.

If reallocation is required for `insert`, all elements will be moved, that's O(n). If reallocation is not required, all the elements to the right of newly inserted elements are moved, but that's still O(n).

---

Cppreference doesn't seem to mention reallocation in Complexity section reliably. For example, [`resize()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) mentions possible additional complexity in Complexity section, but [`push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) and [`insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) mention reallocation only in the function description. Might be worth to clean it up one day.

Comment: "amortized constant" is a more precise guarantee than "constant most of the time". It guarantees that calling the function n times in succession  takes at most linear time (strictly, not amortized). Thus, there is a strict upper bound on how often push_back() is allowed to trigger a reallocation. I was wondering if such a bound also exists for insert().

Comment: @Simon is there a strict upper bound on how often it's allowed to reallocate, or the average complexity of that reallocation needs to be below a constant? You can reallocate an infinite number of times as long as cost of such allocations doesn't grow faster than the number of times you expect to allocate right? Asking for clarification on my end.

Comment: @JohnFilleau Yes you are right. To the best of my understanding "amortized constant" means "repeating the operation n times is (worst-case) linear in total". How that is achieved (exponentially growing buffer, or a fixed buffer of size `.max_size()`, or something complicated involving virtual memory mapping), is up the implementation.